# Can we avoid the default constructor in this case?

Tags: c++

**Observation**: The constructor of ClassMain needs to call `Init` before it can constructor a member variable `a`. Since the `ClassA` has no default constructor, the code doesn't compile.

```
ClassA
{
public:
    // This class has no default constructor
    ClassA(...){}
};

class ClassMain
{
public:
    ClassMain(...) {
        Init(...);
        a = ClassA(...); // error: ClassA has no default constructor
                         // a has to been constructed after the Init is called!
    }
    ClassMain(...) {
            Init(...);
            call other functions
            a = ClassA(...);
    }

private:
    // initialize environment
    void Init(...) {}

private:
    ClassA a;
};
```

Question> The simple solution is to provide a default constructor for `ClassA`. However, I would like to know whether there is a better solution to address the issue above?

Comment: ... there is, do not depend on two phase initialization

Comment: If you can't refactor this using the suggestions below, you can make `a` `std::unique_ptr<ClassA> a;` and then dynamically allocate it after `Init()` has been called.

Comment: This sounds like a poor design decision was made somewhere along the way and could potentially be an XY problem here ...

Comment: @Zac, may you propose a better design?

Comment: @q0987: To propose a better design we would need some idea of what `Init` does for you.

Comment: @aschepler, you can assume that `Init` sets up database connections.

Comment: @q0987:  And what is the reason you don't want to set up those database connections in the constructor?  Additionally, are we to assume you have wrapped (or are using a wrapper) for your database connections?

Answer (score 3):

The obvious solution is to call `Init()` from the initializer list of an early member or a base class. Once this subobject is constructed its results can be passed to the constructors of other subobjects. For example, when defining stream classes I typically privately inherit from a virtual base containing the stream buffer:

```
struct somebuf_base {
    somebuf sbuf;
    // ...
};
class somestream
    : private virtual somebuf_base
    , public std::ostream
{
public:
    somestream(someargs)
        : somebuf_base(someargs)
        , std::ostream(&this->sbuf) {
    }
    // ...
};
```

Since base classes are constructed in the order they appear but virtual bases before non-virtual bases, the base class containing the `sbuf` member is constructed first. Its constructor replaces your `Init()` function.

When using C++ as of the 2011 revision, you might also use forwarding constructors to share logic between multiple constructors.

Comment: We should adopt "vase class" as a shorthand for "virtual base class" [typo joke].

Comment: @aschepler: if that's the only typo I introduced while typing this response on a phone it is pretty good...

Comment: Do you need virtual inheritance here, though?

Comment: @DavisHerring: in this case virtual inheritance is used because `std::ostream` has a `virtual` base (`std::ios`) and without virtual inheritance `somebuf_base` would be constructed only after the `std::ios` subobject as `virtual` base classes are constructed first (and, actually more importantly, destroyed last and there is a `flush` call in `std::ostream`'s destructor). The objective of the construction is to construct `std::ios` with a pointer to a readily constructed `std::streambuf`.

Comment: Right, thanks, but it's _only_ the destructor (and its callbacks in particular) where that matters: `somestream` is of course directly initializing `std::ios` with its default constructor.

Answer (score 2):

The better solution is not to require an `Init` function at all. You're trying to reinvent constructors, and breaking their design in the process.

If `Init` does too much work for a constructor, then do it outside and pass the resulting resources into `ClassMain` as a constructor argument; notice how you're already doing all the work in the constructor's scope anyway, thereby not gaining anything appreciable over proper initialisation.

Of course, if you must perform a ton of work before initialising `a`, and you cannot pass in a `ClassA&` from the outside and initialise from that, then you're simply going to have to have `a` be an indirect member.

There is *one* nasty workaround you could use: have `Init` actually be a base constructor...

Comment: The main reason why I use `Init` is that class `ClassMain` has overloaded constructors each calling the same procedure `Init`. It is not a good idea here to let the user do the work of `Init` because the content of `Init` should be hidden from the user.

Comment: @Lightness, What about Exceptions? I find that my complex classes have 'Init' functions since I don't want Ctors to throw exceptions or fail (on anything other then memory allocation).
As a result anything that contains these classes has Init functions etc... Init functions are not private though more like file.open / file.close

Comment: @odedsh: Constructors should throw exceptions, if any part of initialization can't be completed.  It's just destructors you need to avoid them in.

Comment: @odedsh: And when `Init` fails? The exception propagates to your constructors. This is not a bad thing...

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to take a pointer to ClassA; So, you can instantiate it whenever you want.(after the init())
If you used a pointer, don't forget to implement the virtual destructor and release the allocated memory for the ClassA *a

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must call some function at the start of your constructor, and can't put that setup into some base class or early-constructed member, you could use this ugly trick:

```
ClassMain::ClassMain(int main_param)
  : a( (Init(init_arg), class_a_arg1), class_a_arg2 )
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case: No, we cannot avoid that.

The reason is that when calling `Init` or any other member function you are guaranteed by the language that the object you are in exists. As `a` is a member of `ClassMain` it must be constructed before any function in `ClassMain` can be called.

The only chance that you have here is to refactor the code.